# Firing change and ready event in a single function through jquery

Tags: jquery

I don't want to write the same code for change and ready. So how to combine both the event in a single function?

```
$('#c_country').ready(function(){                              
     var austaffinitycost=<%=affinityServerCostList.get(3) %>;   //getting the data from database
     if($('#c_country').val()=="Australia"){                     //c_country is a input filed
         $('#sl_cost').val(austaffinitycost);
     }
     else{
         $('#sl_cost').val("4");
     }
 }).trigger('change');                                          //firing the change event
```

Comment: The ready event only exists for the document and it’s a special jquery construct.

Comment: What I want is, I want to put a particular value when the page is loaded, and change it upon drop down change option. I can do it with 2 different function. But I want to wrap these actions into single function. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To further elabourate on my comment, [the `.ready()` function is actually a special jQuery construct](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) which is a polyfill/alias for `DOMContentLoaded` event, and therefore is only useful when you use as such: `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`:

> The `.ready()` method offers a way to run JavaScript code as soon as the page's Document Object Model (DOM) becomes safe to manipulate.

Also, even though most people still use `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`, the official documentation recommends using `$(function() { ... })` instead.

---

If you want the logic to run both when the document is ready **and** when `#c_country` fires an onchange event, you can simply abstract it into a separate function. Then, invoke that function on DOM ready and in the onchange event handler separately:

```
function setCost() {
    var austaffinitycost = <%=affinityServerCostList.get(3) %>;
    if ($('#c_country').val() === 'Australia') {
        $('#sl_cost').val(austaffinitycost);
    } else {
        $('#sl_cost').val('4');
    }
}

 $(function() {
    $('#c_country').change(function() {
        setCost();
    });

    setCost();
 });
```

Some pro-tips:

- Always use `===` when possible, it's much safer
- Personally I would not encode server data as such: `var austaffinitycost = <%=affinityServerCostList.get(3) %>;`. If ever possible, rely on asynchronous request to fetch server-side data
- You can shorten your if/else statement using tenary operators, i.e.

  ```
  $('#sl_cost').val($('#c_country').val() === 'Australia' ? austaffinitycost : '4');
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Now, I am using ajax for getting the server side data, instead of passing it directly to the script.